# Angular Javascript return the value of dynamic options on select change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a select input and I am using `*ngFor` on the options to let the user select from an dynamic array I am getting from the database

```
<select formControlName="destination_id" (change)="onSelectDestination($any($event.target).value)"
    <option *ngFor="let destination of destinations" [ngValue]="destination.id" class="p-3">
        {{ destination.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

The function

```
onSelectDestination(id: any) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

The problem here is that returns the index of the item and the value

for example: if I chose the third item in the select input it returns this `2: 27`

`2:`  is the index and `27` is the id I want

I used `substr(3, 2)` but it's making problems when the index or the id is bigger than two or three letters

What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: What does your `destination` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace `[value]` in place of `[ngValue]`

value is refer to string and ngValue reference to object which includes the index + value.